# Showing back order message on Product View Page

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, view, backorder

Using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event  I am trying to show the Back Order Message on the Product View Page but I am not getting the product id from the Observer(Id of Configurable Product Variation). I am only getting the parent Id(Configurable Product Id).

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please share the code which you have use?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```